# Create an HTML document using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am new to HTML Agility Pack (HAP), and trying to create HTML document from scratch using this pack.

I am not sure if I am going in the right direction with it, so basically I am creating HtmlNodes for all the tags and adding attributes to it when needed. These HtmlNodes are then appended appropriately

Below is the smaple code (vb.net) for creating an HTML document using HAP.

```
    Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

    ' head
    Dim headNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<head></head>")
    Dim titleNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<title>| Striven</title>")
    Dim metaNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no""/>")

    ' style
    Dim styleNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<style></style>")
    styleNode.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css")

    Dim styleContent As String = "
                    body {
                        margin: 0;
                        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, ""Segoe UI"", Roboto, ""Helvetica Neue"", Arial, ""Noto Sans"", sans-serif, ""Apple Color Emoji"", ""Segoe UI Emoji"", ""Segoe UI Symbol"", ""Noto Color Emoji"";
                        font-size: 1rem;
                        font-weight: 400;
                        line-height: 1.5;
                        color: #212529;
                        text-align: left;
                        background-color: #fff;
                    }

                    .p-style
                    {
                        width: 100%; 
                        color: #555555; 
                        font-family: ""Helvetica Neue"", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
                        font-size: 14px; 
                        line-height: 22px;
                    }

                    .table-items
                    {
                        width: 100%; 
                        color: #555555; 
                        font-family: ""Helvetica Neue"", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
                        font-size: 14px; 
                        line-height: 22px;
                        border-collapse: separate;
                        border-spacing: 0;
                    }

                    .table-items-header
                    {
                        font-weight: normal;
                        color: #4e606d;
                        background-color: #d7e4ee;
                        border: 0;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
                        border-left: 1px solid #dedede;
                    }

                    .table-items-row td
                    {
                        border-style: solid;
                        border-width: 0 0 1px;
                        padding-top: 4px;
                        padding-bottom: 3px;
                        word-wrap: break-word;
                    }
    "
    styleNode.InnerHtml = styleContent

    headNode.AppendChild(titleNode)
    headNode.AppendChild(metaNode)
    headNode.AppendChild(styleNode)

    ' body
    Dim bodyNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<body></body>")

    ' every tags will be appended to this divContainer
    Dim divContainer = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<div></div>")

    Dim h3Node = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<h3></h3>")
    h3Node.InnerHtml = "Testing HTML Agility Pack (HAP)"
    divContainer.AppendChild(h3Node)

    Dim pNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<p></p>")
    pNode.Attributes.Add("class", "p-style")
    pNode.InnerHtml = "This is a sample document that is created using HTML Agility Pack (HAP)"
    divContainer.AppendChild(pNode)

    divContainer.AppendChild(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<br/>"))

    ' Simple table
    Dim tableNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<table></table>")
    tableNode.Attributes.Add("class", "table-items")
    ' Table Header Row
    Dim tableHeadNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<thead></thead>")
    tableHeadNode.Attributes.Add("class", "table-items-header")
    Dim tableHeadRowNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<tr></tr>")
    Dim tableHeadRowCellOneNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<th></th>")
    tableHeadRowCellOneNode.InnerHtml = "Column-1"
    Dim tableHeadRowCellTwoNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<th></th>")
    tableHeadRowCellTwoNode.InnerHtml = "Column-2"
    tableHeadRowNode.AppendChild(tableHeadRowCellOneNode)
    tableHeadRowNode.AppendChild(tableHeadRowCellTwoNode)
    tableHeadNode.AppendChild(tableHeadRowNode)

    ' Table Body
    Dim tableBodyNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<tbody></tbody>")
    ' Table Body Row 1
    Dim tableRowOneNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<tr></tr>")
    tableRowOneNode.Attributes.Add("class", "table-items-row")
    Dim tableRowOneCellOneNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<td></td>")
    tableRowOneCellOneNode.InnerHtml = "Row-1-Column-1"
    Dim tableRowOneCellTwoNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<td></td>")
    tableRowOneCellTwoNode.InnerHtml = "Row-1-Column-2"
    tableRowOneCellTwoNode.Attributes.Add("align", "right")
    tableRowOneNode.AppendChild(tableRowOneCellOneNode)
    tableRowOneNode.AppendChild(tableRowOneCellTwoNode)
    tableBodyNode.AppendChild(tableRowOneNode)

    ' Table Body Row 2
    Dim tableRowTwoNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<tr></tr>")
    tableRowOneNode.Attributes.Add("class", "table-items-row")
    Dim tableRowTwoCellOneNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<td></td>")
    tableRowTwoCellOneNode.InnerHtml = "Row-2-Column-1"
    Dim tableRowTwoCellTwoNode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<td></td>")
    tableRowTwoCellTwoNode.InnerHtml = "Row-2-Column-2"
    tableRowTwoCellTwoNode.Attributes.Add("align", "right")
    tableRowTwoNode.AppendChild(tableRowTwoCellOneNode)
    tableRowTwoNode.AppendChild(tableRowTwoCellTwoNode)
    tableBodyNode.AppendChild(tableRowTwoNode)

    tableNode.AppendChild(tableHeadNode)
    tableNode.AppendChild(tableBodyNode)

    divContainer.AppendChild(tableNode)


    bodyNode.AppendChild(divContainer)
    htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.Add(headNode)
    htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.Add(bodyNode)

    Dim strHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.WriteTo()
```

At the end I am getting the entire html into a string to load it as a pdf.

Few things I want to know is:

1. Is this a correct way to create html using HAP pack?
2. How can I add the main html tag  should it be added as a HtmlNode again?
3. Is there a better way to create HtmlNode, I mean do we have enumerators for html tags instead of using string e.g. HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("< head ></ head >")
4. Can this be directly converted into a pdf which can then be flushed?
5. If there are existing examples for creating html like this then please suggest

Note: We do not want to use XElement, XAttributes for creating html

Comment: If you are converting it to a String, why don't you just use a String? VB.NET has supported multi-lined Strings for a long time now. Edit - it looks like they were introduced in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but using just a string will not suffice. It will be diffcult to read and debug, plus data will be appended to the html based on various conditions and so. We tried using XElement it was neat and nice to read too, but we had certain issue with parser and encoding stuff and want to get rid of it.

Comment: It is my impression that HAP is made more for reading and querying HTML document and perhaps modify them. But not for creating HTML from the ground up. I think you can get it to work, but it will never be a wonderful tool for you.

I would suggest that you consider other tools instead. E.g. ASP.Net MVC. If you need to render in the backend, this can also be possible with ASP.Net. In addition there must be many other templating languages that you can inject some data into.

Comment: You could always use a normal HTML file too and include it in your build.